Please explain "I thought not"
As per title, is there any difference between 'I thought not' and 'I didn't think so'? Thanks.

Both effectively mean the same. "I thought not" puts a little more emphasis on the speaker being right - "What I thought (that something isn't true) is correct!"

In standard American English there is also a sociolect register difference.  "I thought not" is rare in contemporary standard AmE compared to "I didn't think so",  though I think southerners may use it more frequently. If a Yankee says "I thought not", they are probably university educated.

Essentially the same difference applies with present tense "I think not", but it's far more clear-cut. There are plenty of people (Brits as well as Americans) who routinely say "I thought not" if it becomes apparent that their opinion about something not being true is in fact correct, but who would rarely or never say "I think not" to mean "I don't think so" (because they think avoiding "do-support" like that results in inappropriately "posh, affected" constructions).

"I thought not" is more formal sounding. That's the only difference. But you can use the more formal "I didn't think so" (along with the positive affirmation "I think so") with an 'upspeak' inflection to indicate that you are questioning or doubting something you believed.

I thought not is sometimes used in speech, for I didn't think so.
It would usually be in a dialogue:
John: Those were the worst revenue figures I have ever seen.
Harry: I thought not. We've seen worse in other subsidiaries of our holding company.
So, as the title of the book, it implies some pre-existing situation the reader will learn about upon reading the book.
It is high register and sophisticated speech.

I would never use 'I thought not' in that context - I would say "I don't think so".

@KateBunting I would generally not use it at all. It's not an expression I go round using all the time. My point is that it refutes something previously asserted. That's all. It's the kind of expression you hear on the tele (shows) from MI5 guys talking to politicians while sitting in London men's clubs sipping whiskey. And by the way, I wouldn't expect you to have a dialogue like the one in my answer anyway.

As I and FumbleFingers commented above, the usual meaning is "I was correct in thinking that [something] is not true" or "not the case".

@KateBunting Exactly and that is what I meant it to mean in my dialogue. "I was correct in thinking they were not the worst revenue figures I had seen". FF needs to stop answering in comments; it wrecks the site for everyone.

In your dialogue it appears to mean "I don't agree with you" -  (i.e. they are not the worst figures).

@KateBunting I think not, I thought not, I don't think so, I don't agree with you as a response all refer to prior speech and all mean basically the same thing.  I am really not understanding what your point is but I think this is enough discussion.

But "I thought not" doesn't mean "I don't agree with you", it means  "What you say (that something isn't true) is just what I expected."

@KateBunting You said: "Both effectively mean the same". i.e. I thought not means I didn't think so. And I didn't think so is the same basically as I don't agree with you. You're trying to say that "I thought not" can also mean "what you say that isn't true" is also what I think that it isn't true. Yes, but not in my example.

Well, I would use both with the same meaning - and "I don't think so" to contradict someone.
